# Play temporary file to blob Byte Buffer in Scala

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

I use multipart from data to get file from the front end, I can save the file in a server dirctory:

```
request.body.file("fileUpload").map { file =>
  file.ref.moveTo(new File("filename"), true)
}
```

How can instead save this file to the data base as a blob, in other words how can I convert Play API `TemporaryFile` to `java.nio ByteBuffer` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val bytes = Files.readAllBytes(tempFile.file.toPath)
```

gives you an `Array[Byte]`. If you really need a `ByteBuffer`, use `ByteBuffer.wrap`.